# How do I remove duplicate SQL Server 2008 instances after upgrading from SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, upgrade

I've just upgraded an existing SQL Server 2005 to 2008 by running the installer (not the platform installer). It all seems to have worked - there were no errors reported and my code that connects to these databases still works fine.

The problem is, when I try installing SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 I am shown the following error message when I select to add new features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008:

> The SQL Server instance 'SQL1MINUS102'
>   already has an Instance ID '2' that is
>   different than the specified Instance
>   ID 'SQL1MINUS102'. Specifying more
>   than one instance ID for the same SQL
>   Server instance is not supported.

Here is a screenshot of the installation dialog and the setup discovery report:

[Screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2a04077cf4.gif)

Notice that there are two instances with the same name. So any ideas how I should recifiy this so that I can install Management studio?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, Reporting Services was installed on this box so I uninstalled that through Add/Remove Programs, then after a quick reboot the extra instance name was gone and I could continue to install Management Studio 2008.